# R interpreter not working in Zeppelin 0.6.2

Tags: python, r, apache, sparkr, apache-zeppelin

I recently installed apache zeppelin 0.6.2 on Mac OS Siera 10.2, I am able to run the spark and python examples but when I try to run the R codes using either `%r` or `%spark.r` I get an error. I have already set the `SPARK_HOME` and `SCALA_HOME` in .bash_profile. Attaching the error log:

```
INFO [2016-10-31 19:48:10,806] ({pool-2-thread-5} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1477923480756 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkRInterpreter314730576
 INFO [2016-10-31 19:48:10,804] ({pool-1-thread-5} ZeppelinR.java[createRScript]:366) - File /var/folders/_b/2cr99z410sddt8km9p9b9fs80000gn/T/zeppelin_sparkr-6402261059466053567.R created
ERROR [2016-10-31 19:48:20,836] ({pool-1-thread-5} TThreadPoolServer.java[run]:296) - Error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not responding
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that setting SPARK_HOME in .bash_profile is not enough, one needs to also update the zeppelin-env.sh and set SPARK_HOME there as well.